# Using multiple statements under if to merge multiple groups of cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge

Right now, my code says "if any of the cells in column D match these words " ", then merge that cell in the same row from column F to H". What I would like it to do is also merge the two cells in column D, the top cell will have words and the cell below will be blank. I would also like the table to incrementally merge every 3 cells in a row so like after F to H it would skip I and then merge J-L. here is the code:

```
Sub Merge_PlansourceCategories()
Dim RgToMerge As String


For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row
    RgToMerge = ""
    If Cells(i, 4) = "red" or cells (i, 4) = "blue" Then
    RgToMerge = "$F$" & i & ":$H$" & i + 1        



   'for step loop to make this easier?
    With range(RgToMerge)
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Merge_PlansourceCategories()
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 4) = "red" Or Cells(i, 4) = "blue" Then
            For j = 1 To 2
                With Range(Cells(i, j * 4 + 2), Cells(i, j * 4 + 4))
                    .Merge
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With
            Next j
            With Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i + 1, 4))
                .Merge
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

There is really no point in creating RgToMerge as a string and using letters for column names makes it hard to increment.